# I have this error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

why I get this error message can anyone explain me

```
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
```

and my repository function  like this

```
public function getDataFromLink()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->get('https://geoportal.nsdi.gov.mn/alagac/rest/services/HBK_Barilga/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=4326&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&f=geojson&fbclid=IwAR1QV9fQRlek5yYp7fPrtUFEkJHzCoA3YaJGmn7HqrFj3cBThHmnJhB65dk');
    // $response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
    $jsonData = json_decode(json_encode($response));

    return $jsonData;

}
```

Comment: try not to use `https://`, use `http://` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XAMPP server. You can download `cacert.pem` file from the below link and put it in your under `C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem`  and add it's path `php.ini` file

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Put it here

```
C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
```

In your php.ini put this line in this section ("c:\xampp\php\php.ini"):

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

restart your webserver/apache

**OR**

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => '/path/to/cacert.pem']); // add your cacert.pem path directly here
```

[Laracast -> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: thanks for your help. Now I can continue my work :))

Comment: @BaneNeba  Great!! Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: Hey pls accept and upvote the answer so that It will be helpful for others also

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @BaneNeba ok no problem. then just accept the answer